# Display other WP site blog posts in one WP blog

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

Been scouring the Internet for ideas on how to do this. Here's what I'd like to do:

WP Site "A" to be used as a portal of sorts to other WP sites I run, and it will also have it's own blog posts.

WP Site "B" is the first of two external sites with an active blog. Posts have thumbnails and titles.

WP Site "C" is the second of two external sites with an active blog. Posts have thumbnails and titles.

WP Site "A" will have a masonry-style post listing on the homepage, of thumbnails, and post titles that link. I'd like to pull new blog posts from sites "B" and "C" and display them in the same manner: thumbnails, post titles, and links that would lead to the external site. I'd also want this to display them in ascending date order, interspersed together as the new blogs are created.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this, or how to feed external posts into another blog? If it helps, all of these blogs are on the same hosting account, with the same access to their DB's. I have been finding a few RSS-based solutions (and in fact have used one of them to pull single posts into a homepage before, but this is more involved than that), but I'm not sure how to integrate them into the structure of Blog "A" so that they are all grouped together in the same masonry grid.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at WP REST API (http://v2.wp-api.org). This is exactly what you are looking for. With WP REST API you can get **EVERY** element of a post from any site you manage, and display it on any other site. (But you should also implement some form of authentication!)

Example request:

```
http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue
```

"venue" is a custom post type that I use in the real code. The example request is made to get all the venues from the site.

Example response:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 20,
    "date": "2016-06-08T16:37:23",
    "date_gmt": "2016-06-08T16:37:23",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://www.example.com/wp/?post_type=venue&#038;p=20"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-20T11:45:22",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-20T11:45:22",
    "slug": "aquarium-club",
    "type": "venue",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/wp/venue/aquarium-club/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Aquarium Club"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>Aquarium Club. That&#8217;s OK. 7765e546uzfkjglh</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<style>\n.gmap-iframe-container {\nmax-width: 100%;\n}\n.gmap-iframe {\nwidth: 100%;\nheight: 200px;\nmin-width:100%;\n}\n</style>\n<div class=\"gmap-iframe-container\">\n<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2695.565888030695!2d19.052103115616678!3d47.49836967917771!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4741dc402a04eee3%3A0x6869564cd433693c!2sAkv%C3%A1rium+Klub!5e0!3m2!1shu!2shu!4v1466147278469\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen class=\"gmap-iframe\"></iframe></p>\n"
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "<p>Aquarium Club. That&#8217;s OK. 7765e546uzfkjglh &nbsp;</p>\n"
    },
    "featured_media": 0,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "format": "standard",
    "tags": [],
    "meta_data": {
      "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/xBW7DglTDGs"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/20"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/types/venue"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=20"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=20"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "date": "2016-06-08T15:55:04",
    "date_gmt": "2016-06-08T15:55:04",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://www.example.com/wp/?post_type=venue&#038;p=18"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-08T15:55:04",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-08T15:55:04",
    "slug": "durer-kert",
    "type": "venue",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/wp/venue/durer-kert/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Dürer Kert"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": ""
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": ""
    },
    "featured_media": 19,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "format": "standard",
    "tags": [],
    "meta_data": {
      "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/w9saGGpnKlk"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/18"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/types/venue"
        }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media/19"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=18"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=18"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "date": "2016-06-08T14:52:40",
    "date_gmt": "2016-06-08T14:52:40",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://www.example.com/wp/?post_type=venue&#038;p=15"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-08T15:41:27",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-08T15:41:27",
    "slug": "kobuci-kert",
    "type": "venue",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/wp/venue/kobuci-kert/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "KOBUCI Kert"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>This is KOBUCI Kert.</p>\n"
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "<p>This is KOBUCI Kert.</p>\n"
    },
    "featured_media": 17,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "format": "standard",
    "tags": [],
    "meta_data": {
      "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zwNBKh6ghOY"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/15"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/types/venue"
        }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media/17"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=15"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=15"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "date": "2016-06-08T14:12:38",
    "date_gmt": "2016-06-08T14:12:38",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://www.example.com/wp/?post_type=venue&#038;p=13"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-08T14:12:38",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-08T14:12:38",
    "slug": "mupa",
    "type": "venue",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/wp/venue/mupa/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "MÜPA"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>MÜPA is MÜPA. Not bad from a building, is it? A lot of concerts and stuff.</p>\n"
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "<p>MÜPA is MÜPA. Not bad from a building, is it? A lot of concerts and stuff.</p>\n"
    },
    "featured_media": 14,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "format": "standard",
    "tags": [],
    "meta_data": {
      "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/YnOW2rUXuSg"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/13"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/types/venue"
        }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media/14"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=13"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=13"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "date": "2016-06-07T08:36:40",
    "date_gmt": "2016-06-07T08:36:40",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://www.example.com/wp/?post_type=venue&#038;p=8"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-08T13:22:39",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-08T13:22:39",
    "slug": "some-venue",
    "type": "venue",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/wp/venue/some-venue/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "National Concert Hall"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>This is the next venue for REST API. Just to see more than one. This should be the general description of this venue. This is the venue &#8211; what is it? 5324</p>\n"
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "<p>This is the next venue for REST API. Just to see more than one. This should be the general description of this venue. This is the venue &#8211; what is it? 5324</p>\n"
    },
    "featured_media": 9,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "format": "standard",
    "tags": [],
    "meta_data": {
      "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/camVVzjGheQ"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/8"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/types/venue"
        }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media/9"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=8"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=8"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "date": "2016-06-07T08:33:13",
    "date_gmt": "2016-06-07T08:33:13",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://www.example.com/wp/?post_type=venue&#038;p=7"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-08T13:20:27",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-08T13:20:27",
    "slug": "orchestra-hall",
    "type": "venue",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/wp/venue/orchestra-hall/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Music Academy"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>This is a venue &#8211; it is made of a custom post type, and I get it with REST API.</p>\n"
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "<p>This is a venue &#8211; it is made of a custom post type, and I get it with REST API.</p>\n"
    },
    "featured_media": 11,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "format": "standard",
    "tags": [],
    "meta_data": {
      "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZL6BFCxNGZ8"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/7"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/types/venue"
        }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media/11"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=7"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=7"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Note:
-- the example result above is a bit customised to my needs - so you may see a bit other result.
-- a request for a single venue would look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/20
```

As you can see you can get every piece of information you need from the other site - and you can even customise the response to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was actually just looking at the Rest API earlier after seeing another related question on here. On a scale of 1-10, where do you rank the complexity of actually updating the code to integrate things as I've described? I'm proficient in PHP but this looks like it could be pretty complex. Any thoughts?

Comment: From 1-10? I think it's harder to rate it than to do it :) REST API is a plugin (actually it was planned to be WP core function in WP 4.5), so installing it is a piece of cake. Then, the API page (and other tutorials) provide a lot of example code on retrieving the data you want - and I think, when the response can be seen on your screen, it becomes a game of placing and formatting array elements where you want. I suggest using some testing software (I use the Postman extension for Chrome) to see the results. Authentication is another matter - it can be hard, depending on the type you chose.

Comment: Also, one other question - do you imagine that it's possible to use REST API to do what I've describe and simply link the posts from other sites to those particular sites? Ex: on Blog A, click a link to a Blog B post, and Blog B opens on that post detail page?

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it. Will let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: You're welcome! :) I've found the WP REST API to be what they promised it would be: a very big step for WP towards becoming a full-fledged CMS.

Comment: Hello - I started looking into this tonight. A bit over my head so going to take some time to figure it out. A few questions, using the same scenario I described above: The REST API goes on the site that will be displaying content from other WP sites, correct? Is there an interface of any kind for it? And, lastly, on the blogs that will be feeding into site "A", must the REST API be installed there as well?

Comment: No, the REST API must be on the "source" sites - the main site has the query (named 'request' in my example above), and the other sites' REST API must respond to this query (they send the data, if they can parse the query - without the REST API they cannot). Think of it like this: the main site "asks the question" and the other sites "answer with a JSON string". The main site need not have the REST API, but it may get useful - you could use the same query structure with all three sites, so you would get the same response (this way you need to build a parser only once for the three sources).

Comment: That is why you also need to use athentication - if your sites have the REST API installed without authentication, anyone can query them, and they will try to give a response - very good base for an attack like DDOS.

Comment: Thanks again, will look into that. I used the REST API plugin in my browser and was able to see the post code.  FYI I'm using the Rest API Embed plugin on the site that will display the posts. I've used the url shortcode and it's accessing the data, just not displaying it. Do you have any suggestions on how to best integrate this with existing theme PHP to pull this off? Assuming that I need to somehow combine the code for pulling the posts into the existing PHP for the blog's own posts. Trying to figure out how I will integrate them all together using the blog's masonry layout and styles.

Comment: With existing themes I would look into the part where it queries the DB for posts (e.g. WP_Query, get_posts(), etc.) , and try to exchange it for a REST API query (also changing the data parsing functions according to the REST API response). If that works then you're on the track: all three sites can be queried the same way, their responses can be handled in the same way - so there won't be any difference whether the data comes from site "A", site "B" or site "C". Problems might arise if there are timeouts though (a site does not send the response in time) - maybe a callback can work it out.